# Scala: Removing first 2 directories from a String

Tags: scala

I have a string that looks like this `"./path1/path2/path3/path4/etc/file"`

I would like to just remove the first 2 paths and return a string that looks like this:

`"path3/path4/etc/file"`

How can I do this using Scala?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about simple: `s.split("/").drop(3).mkString("/")`

In this statement firstly you split path by `/`, next remove first 3 tokens (as first one will be `.` in your case) and finally merge tokens together to create new path.

Answer (score 7):

If you're dealing with filesystem paths, it might be wise to use Java's `Path` class that's designed for this sort of thing.

```
scala> import java.nio.file.Paths
import java.nio.file.Paths

scala> val p = Paths.get("./path1/path2/path3/path4/etc/file")
p: java.nio.file.Path = ./path1/path2/path3/path4/etc/file

scala> p.subpath(3, p.getNameCount())
res0: java.nio.file.Path = path3/path4/etc/file
```

Comment: +1. I think this answer should be accepted instead of @norbert-radyk's because this way 1) performs better, 2) is more intuitive and 3) is specifically designed for what OP asks, so it would be more clear in the code.